# Custom widget not being marked safe

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a custom widget to display a choice field as a row of buttons.

So far, I've copied the code from the Django source for rendering a radio-choice field as my starting point:

```
@html_safe
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ButtonInput(SubWidget):

  input_type = 'radio'

  def __init__(self, name, value, attrs, choice, index):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
    self.attrs = attrs
    self.choice_value = force_text(choice[0])
    self.choice_label = force_text(choice[1])
    self.index = index
    if 'id' in self.attrs:
        self.attrs['id'] += "_%d" % self.index
    self.value = force_text(self.value)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.render()

  def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None):
      if self.id_for_label:
          label_for = format_html(' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
      else:
          label_for = ''
      attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
      return format_html(
          '<label{}>{} {}</label>', label_for, self.tag(attrs), self.choice_label
      )

  def is_checked(self):
      return self.value == self.choice_value

  def tag(self, attrs=None):
      attrs = attrs or self.attrs
      final_attrs = dict(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=self.name, value=self.choice_value)
      if self.is_checked():
          final_attrs['checked'] = 'checked'
      return format_html('<input{} />', flatatt(final_attrs))

  @property
  def id_for_label(self):
      return self.attrs.get('id', '')


class ButtonFieldRenderer(ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = ButtonInput


class ButtonSelect(RendererMixin, Select):
    renderer = ButtonFieldRenderer
    _empty_value = ''
```

My issue is that this code renders the correct HTML, but it's not marked safe - the HTML code renders onto the page. Given that this code is essentially copied straight from the Django source code, this is very surprising.

What is missing? How do I make my widget class html-safe?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Have you copied the code from the appropriate version?

Comment: @Alasdair 1.9, and I've checked, there isn't any difference

Comment: Try using the `@html_safe` decorator for the `ButtonFieldRenderer` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the strings in the render method for u'' worked for me

```
  def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None):
      if self.id_for_label:
          label_for = format_html(u' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
      else:
          label_for = ''
      attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
      return format_html(
          u'<label{}>{} {}</label>', label_for, self.tag(attrs), self.choice_label
      )
```

Comment: in my case neither with `@html_sage` or `@python_2_unicode_compatible` decorators worked